# Changing Color Of Multible Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive got an Set of Buttons that should change the color when pressed.
I tried it with getelementybyclassname but when i press a differnt button the color changes for all buttons. My goal is to make some sort of Selector where you can choose your criteria and depending on the criteria a final result will be shown

```js
function changecolor(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].style.color="blue";
  }
```

```html
<h2><span class="primary-text">Choose </span>your criteria</h2>
          <button class="button"type="button" id="lightframe" onclick="changecolor()">easy to handle</button>
          <button class="button"type="button" id="outdoor" onclick="changecolor()">small</button>
          <button class="button"type="button" id="smallsize" onclick="changecolor">cheap</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the button to the function

```js
function changecolor(button){
  button.style.color = "blue";
  }
```

```html
<h2><span class="primary-text">Choose </span>your criteria</h2>
      <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this)">easy to handle</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this)">small</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this)">cheap</button>
```

Or like this

```js
function changecolor(){
  this.style.color = "blue";
  }
```

```html
<h2><span class="primary-text">Choose </span>your criteria</h2>
      <button type="button" onclick="changecolor.apply(this)">easy to handle</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="changecolor.apply(this)">small</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="changecolor.apply(this)">cheap</button>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to trigger color of your buttons I would highly recommend using css instead of manipulating on style attribute. jQuery will be very handy for this

```js
$(".button").on("click", function () {
 if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
   $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
  else {
   $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><span class="primary-text">Choose </span>your criteria</h2>
      <button type="button" class="button">easy to handle</button>
      <button type="button" class="button">small</button>
      <button type="button" class="button">cheap</button>
```

Comment: hey thanks this worked for me. only single question how can i manage to change the color again when i press the button again? thanks for your help again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function changecolor(idElement){
  var elements = document.getElementById(idElement).style.color="blue";
  }
```

```html
<h2><span class="primary-text">Choose </span>your criteria</h2>
          <button class="button"type="button" id="lightframe" onclick="changecolor('lightframe')">easy to handle</button>
          <button class="button"type="button" id="outdoor" onclick="changecolor('outdoor')">small</button>
          <button class="button"type="button" id="smallsize" onclick="changecolor('smallsize')">cheap</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try jQuery

```
<h2><span class="primary-text">Choose </span>your criteria</h2>
      <button class="button" type="button" id="lightframe">easy to handle</button>
      <button class="button" type="button" id="outdoor">small</button>
      <button class="button" type="button" id="smallsize">cheap</button>



//This code will only change the one that is selected

    $('.button').click(function() {
      $(this).css("color", "blue");
    });
```